# Can we use two prepositions in a row?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

for example
"Ab in den Urlaub"
Are "Ab" and "in" both prepositions?
If they come in a row, the next word changes according to which preposition?

Comment: Normally it best to include a full sentence for context, not just a short phrase. I googled the phrase and came up with a TV show from the early 2000's; the first episode title was "Ab in den Urlaub mit den Klostertalern und ihren Freunden". It's still not a complete sentence but perhaps it's helpful. (For those who don't know, _Klostertaler_ is the name of an Austrian musical group.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible in German. Most notorious for this is the preposition *mit*, but other prepositions can do that, too.

> Am 15. Juni geht es ab in den Urlaub.

It's best to see those combinations as two-word prepositions on their own with a slightly different meaning than the second preposition would have alone. The required case follows the second preposition.

The combination *ab in* emphasises the departure (to let go — „ab“) on top of the direction.

Oh, and you can also say

> Der Hund kommt mit ab in den Urlaub.

with three prepositions in a row but that's very “street”.

Comment: I doubt that *ab* is a preposition here. It seems to have a role similar to *weg* in *Wir fahren weg in den Urlaub* where *weg* clearly is not a preposition.

Comment: @RHa The *Ab* in theater plays comes to mind where *Ab* means leaving the stage.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of speech it is, but I'd translate the phrase "ab in den Urlaub" (with no additional context) as "away on vacation", and "away" definitely is an adverb in English. The examples I found on DWDS seem to imply there's some kind of ellipsis going on with the phrase. For example "Tüte zukleben und ab in den Müll," is given, but I would have thought "werfen" is needed for the second part to be grammatical. Since the argument for "ab" being a preposition here is dubious, I'd say that the case of the following noun is determined by "in". Otherwise it would be "ab in dem Urlaub".

Comment: Thank you for your answer
And also this phrase was a title

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

But only *in* is a preposition, *ab* in the sentence you gave is an adverb. See [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ab#Adverb) the meaning [6].

Comment: @Olafant - Right. It's certainly possible that "ab" can be used as an adverb, but I also checked DWDS and English Wiktionary and couldn't find any documentation for it. But "absence of evidence is not evidence of absence," as they say, and there are cases where dictionaries do no account for every possible use of a word. On the other hand absence of evidence is also not evidence of presence, so I'd say dictionaries are really helpful either way in this case.